# Comprobar si existe una variable en python

Tags: php, python, variables

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy aprendiendo python y vengo de PHP, por ejemplo en php tenemos la función `isset` para comprobar si existe una variable, en python hay alguna forma de hacer esto mismo? por ejemplo en php sería así:

```
if(isset($variable))
{
  echo "la variable existe"
}
else
{
  echo "la variable no existe"
}
```

En python como podría hacer eso? Desde ya gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si, puedes usar try/except, ya que si la variable no esta definida lanza una excepción llamada [NameError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NameError)

Por ejemplo

```
try:
    print(not_defined)
except NameError:
    print("La variable no esta definida")
else:
    print("El conteido es:", not_defined)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo hice lo que dijiste y si funcionó

Answer (score 4):

Todas las variables creadas se guardan en el diccionario global de variables de python, el cual es accesible mediante `globals()`  por lo que podemos hacer jn simple if

```py
if "name_variable" in globals():
    print("variable existe")
else:
    print("variable no existe")
```

Solo recuerda poner el nombre de la variable como string

Comment: Creo que estaría bien que menciones `locals()` también, ya que depende del `scope` que este, tiene que usar `globals` o `locals`

Comment: Es verdad, pero me limito a gñobañs dado que más probable requerirlo en un contexto global que en algo limitado

Comment: @MitaCloud locals no contiene las variables que están fuera de la función pero que pueden ser accedidas dentro de ella. En mi opinion una mejor alternativa es la que propusiste vos (perdon Christian, no tengo intención de ofender)